Computing or sampling from a posterior with samples observed through a dimensional reduction transformation
Let $\boldsymbol \theta$ be a vector of parameters, with a known prior $\pi(\boldsymbol \theta)$.
Let $\boldsymbol x_1,...,\boldsymbol x_n$ be i.i.d. samples with $\boldsymbol x|\boldsymbol \theta$ known.
The problem is that we do not observe $\boldsymbol x_i$, but $\boldsymbol g(\boldsymbol x_i)$. Here $\boldsymbol g$ is a dimensional reduction transformation. How to numerically compute the posterior $\pi(\boldsymbol \theta | \boldsymbol g(\boldsymbol x_1),...,g(\boldsymbol x_n))$ or sampling from it efficiently?
A simple example is here. For a rectangle, the width $w\sim {\rm Uniform}(0, a)$ and the length $l\sim {\rm Uniform}(0,b)$, and $(a,b)$ follows a known prior.
But we cannot observe $(w,l)$. Instead, we can observe the area $s = w\cdot l$.
How to compute the posterior $\pi(a,b|s)$ numerically or sampling from it?

Your "simple example" might benefit from giving an explicit prior for $(a,b)$.  I suspect you could also need to say whether, conditional on $a$ and $b$, $w$ and $l$ are independent and if not then how they are realted.

This sounds like a simple matter of computing the density of $g(x)$ by general principles.

@Xi'an Since $\boldsymbol g$ might be very complicated, it is generally impossible to compute the closed form of $f({\boldsymbol g(\boldsymbol X)}|\boldsymbol \theta)$.

If the transform$$g:\rm X\longrightarrow \rm G$$is too complex to analytically determine the density of the distribution of $g(X)$, a plain solution is to reconstruct $X$ conditional on $g(X)$ and $\theta$ via a Gibbs sampler:
At iteration $t$,

generate $X_1^t,\ldots,X_n^t$ conditional on $g(X_1),\ldots,g(X_n)$ and $\theta^{t-1}$
generate $\theta^t$ conditional on $X_1^t,\ldots,X_n^t$

This is for instance what we did in our recent Insufficient Gibbs sampling paper for the specific case of $g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ being observed and corresponding to quantile and/or MAD statistics.
In the event the (constrained) generation of $X_1^t,\ldots,X_n^t$ is too complex, as suggested by Guillaume Dehaene, an ABC algorithm can take over by simulating

$\theta^t$ from the prior $\pi(\cdot)$
$X_1^t,\ldots,X_n^t$ from the sampling distribution $f(\cdot|\theta^t)$

and only keeping the $\theta^t$'s for which $g(X_1^t),\ldots,g(X_n^t)$ is close enough to the observed $g(X_1^0),\ldots,g(X_n^0)$

And if g is not related to the quantiles / order statistics which you make heavy use if your paper as far as I can tell, would you suggest to use an ABC-like step or do you have another possibility in mind?

@GuillaumeDehaene: This paper is simply an illustration of the principle. If $g$ is of another type, the reconstitution of the sample given the $g(x_i)$'s must be explored anew. If this is not achievable, I would suggest directly running an ABC based on the $g(x_i)$'s, that is simulating new samples such that the generated $g(x_i)$'s are close to the observed $g(x_i)$'s, with or without an MCMC structure.
